# Node.js : Specify files to unzip with zlib + tar

Tags: node.js, zlib

An installation process is downloading a `.tar.gz` archive, then extract the files to a destination directory. However, not all the files in the archive are required, and I'd like to specify which files should be extracted. The naïve way would be to delete the unnecessary files after extraction, but I'd like a "cleaner" way and filter out instead.

Is this possible?

The (relevant) code I have so far is (stripped for readability)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var tar = require('tar');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var log = console.log;

var tarball = 'path/to/downloaded/archive.tar.gz';
var dest = 'path/to/destination';

fs.createReadStream(tarball)
  .on("error", log)
  .pipe(zlib.Unzip())
  .pipe(tar.Extract({ path: dest }))
  .on("end", log);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works similar to the [`unzip`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/unzip) module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var tar = require('tar');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var path = require('path');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp'); // used to create directory tree

var log = console.log;

var tarball = 'path/to/downloaded/archive.tar.gz';
var dest    = 'path/to/destination';

fs.createReadStream(tarball)
  .on('error', log)
  .pipe(zlib.Unzip())
  .pipe(tar.Parse())
  .on('entry', function(entry) {
    if (/\.js$/.test(entry.path)) { // only extract JS files, for instance
      var isDir     = 'Directory' === entry.type;
      var fullpath  = path.join(dest, entry.path);
      var directory = isDir ? fullpath : path.dirname(fullpath);

      mkdirp(directory, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (! isDir) { // should really make this an `if (isFile)` check...
          entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullpath));
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: @rynop good catch, although I would perform that check before calling `mkdirp()`.

Comment: lol ya duh. fixed. Also I'm seeing the files within the .tar.gz get corrupted on disk after extraction. You ever seen this before? Files get onto disk with the correct name and structure, but jar's inside the file are corrupted. Omitting the extract only JS files line and using tar.Extract() this does not happen

Comment: @rynop I've used similar code to extract tar files, and it has always worked for me. If you have a sample tar file for me, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @robertklep I appreciate it: http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_2015-01-27.tar.gz  You can see my code that is working at https://github.com/doapp-ryanp/dynamodb-local/blob/master/index.js#L105 - if i change to `tar.Parse()` and use your logic the binary files get corrupted (different size)

Comment: @rynop this seems to work just fine for me: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/01dd2c64a0fe9f5483d5 (feel free to leave comments there instead of here :-)

Comment: if rynop is on windows and robertklep on *nix like system, then this argument on corrupted file stands.
There has to be normalization performed for file paths. \\ win, / nix.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359485/how-to-download-and-unzip-a-zip-file-in-memory-in-nodejs?rq=1) to find a good solution.

By the way, in the [zlib-documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_unzip_buf_callback) you'll see that you can specify a "buffer" calling .unzip().

Comment: No, the archive can be quite large and I don't want to allocate that much RAM. The memory footprint must be at it's minimum. Besides, the archives contains a directory structure and what you are proposing does not apply.

Comment: I have to read an extracted file from the tar. When should I call my read function? I tried onClose but my file is not fully written till then. You can see my code.

Comment: fs.createReadStream(filename)
  .pipe(zlib.Unzip())
  .pipe(new tar.Parse())
  .on('entry', function(entry) 
   {
    { 
     var isDir     = 'Directory' === entry.type;
     var fullpath  = path.join(dest, entry.path);
     var directory = isDir ? fullpath : path.dirname(fullpath);
     mkdirp(directory, function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     if (! isDir) 
     { 
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullpath)
      .on('error', function(e){alert('Error');})
);
     }});}
   }).on('close', function(){setTimeout(readXMLFile(sysObject.path + '\\layout_new.xml'),0);})